# How to compare multiple spatial point patterns over a polygon

Tags: polygon, r, point, spatial-statistics

I have multiple point pattern distributions over the same region/polygon. Each point pattern distribution has different number of points.

Here is an example of two spatial point patterns for the region/polygon, the first one covers the polygon, while in the second not all of the polygon area is covered by the point pattern.

[image]

How can I compare the distributions within a polygon?

I prefer a solution for this problem in R.

Comment: What do you mean by 'compare'? There are a lot of ways of looking at point distributions - nearest-neighbour, point densities, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would divide the entropy (there is a R package) of the point positions by the entropy of the same number of evenly spaced points inside the polygon. I will not always be possible to have exactly the same number of points, but you can approximate the required spacing based on the area of the polygon (sqrt(num_point/area_polygon)).

Another index could be using a tessalation with your points to create a partition of the polygon, then look at the coefficient of variation of the areas.